# Why is there no Permanency spell in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-3.5e, edition-comparison, designer-reasons

In 3.5e, there's the *permanency* spell, which makes other spells permanent. There isn't a spell like this in 5e, but there are ways to make specific spells permanent, usually by casting it in the same spot every day for a year. In this way, the need for permanency has been reduced, but it still would have some uses, like creating a permanent detect thoughts aura.

**Have the designers given any reasoning as to why this spell did not make it through editions?** Absent of that, is there a consensus in the community that has been reached (e.g. "It would have been too powerful")?